# changing the label of x-axis in gnuplot for milliseconds values

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting sin wave in gnu-plot and taking values of x-axis in milliseconds.

I have been using this code:

```
set timefmt "%S"                           
set format x "%.3S"                      
plot 3*sin(100*pi*x)
```

The graph that I got is like this:

[image: sine wave]
but i want to show the x-axis ticks as 0,5,10 instead of 0.005, .015.
How can i do that?

Comment: Please show a *minimal* script which shows what you are doing. The tick labels look strange. Usually, just scale x by 1000 to get what you want, `plot (3.0 * x /10 * pi)`

Comment: thanks....its done! actually i was trying : `set format x "%0.3S"`   this. but again, thank u for replying!

Comment: OK, so either include your original code snippet in your question, or delete the question. As it is now it is of no use for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%S` format is only for time data, the `set timefmt` applies only when reading in a data set.
Basically the x-values are just numbers, you give them a unit and a meaning.

So, if you want to plot `3*sin(100*pi*x)` (with x being seconds), but want to have the xrange given in milliseconds you must replace `x` with `x/1000.0`:

```
plot 3*sin(x * 10.0/pi)
```

Comment: I thought so, but I still wanted to give a reasonably verbose answer for other readers :)